# Не работает alias в next js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, nextjs

tsconfig

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@layout/*": ["src/layout/*"],
      "@components/*": ["src/components"]
    },
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

компонент

```js
import { Footer, Header } from '@layout'

const BaseLayout = ({ children }) => (
  <>
    <Header />
    {children}
    <Footer />
  </>
)

export default BaseLayout
```

ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: может быть нужно указать конкретный компонент? типа `import { Header } from '@layout/header'` и `import { Footer } from '@layout/footer'`

Comment: А какая у вас структура проекта?